# How can I make a status, which appears in html for the client, if it is on or off

Tags: arduino-c++

I made this code:

```
if(readString.indexOf("?on") >0)//checks for on
          {
            alfa.write(80); 
            Serial.println("Energy on");
          }
          if(readString.indexOf("?off") >0)//checks for off
          {
            alfa.write(180); 
            Serial.println("Energy off");
          }
```

And I want to print a status to the client showing if the energy is on or off, but, I really don't know how to do it.
Anyone have an idea what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find some substring in `readString()`, you should use something like this:

```
String incoming = "";
if(incoming.substring(0, incoming.length()) == "?on")//checks for on
{
    alfa.write(80); 
    Serial.println("Energy on");
}
else if(incoming.substring(0, incoming.length()) == "?off")//checks for off
{
    alfa.write(180); 
    Serial.println("Energy off");
}
```